# How I can prove the equality $P^{P_{\operatorname{space}}}=NP^{P_{\operatorname{space}}}=P_{\operatorname{space}}^{P_{\operatorname{space}}}$

Tags: computational-complexity, np

I know how to prove that if $A \in P^{P_{\operatorname{space}}}$ then $A \in NP^{P_{\operatorname{space}}}$ and $A \in P_{\operatorname{space}}^{P_{\operatorname{space}}}$. 
I don't know how to prove that if $A \in P_{\operatorname{space}}^{P_{\operatorname{space}}}$ then $A \in NP^{P_{\operatorname{space}}}$ and $A \in P^{P_{\operatorname{space}}}$ and if $A \in NP^{P_{\operatorname{space}}}$ then $A \in P^{P_{\operatorname{space}}}$.

Comment: Please use TeX properly.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my changes to the TeX code; computer scientists might prefer $PSPACE$, but I think $P_{\operatorname{space}}$ is easier on the eyes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Complexity theory is on-topic here at MathOverflow.

Comment: there is http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cc.complexity-theory where many people who know all about complexity classes hang out

Comment: And meanwhile, we also have such people here at MO, with over 700 questions in the computational-complexity tag, currently followed by 122 users. Please don't reflexively close questions on this topic.

Comment: and for some reason it's not even possible to mention  cstheory.stackexchange.com or  cs.stackexchange.com as possible venues to migrate...

Comment: I am not saying that complexity theory questions have no place here, I am saying that this particular one is way too technical to be of interest here.

Comment: This is an exercise, not a research-level question.

Comment: @BenMcKay do people really use the notation $P_{\text{space}}$ for that complexity class? I've never seen it.